# How to Add Error Bars on Barplot With Percentages

Tags: r, ggplot2

New to R, apologies in advance. 
Created the attached barplot using ggplot2 with percentages

[image: img1]

I am trying to add error bars to it and I can't seem to find a way to do so. I'm not sure if my data will work as is or if it needs to be altered, data table is below as well

[image: img2]

I can't seem to figure out how to keep percentages and add error bars. I have tried `geom_errorbars` in various ways but this will not work. I tried the following and the error bars are missing and averages are listed, no percentages:

```
SI_avgs <- Shift_Injuries %>%
  group_by(Shift) %>% 
  summarize(Avg = mean(counnt),
        SD = sd(counnt),
        N = n(counnt)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(L_CI = Avg - 1.96 * sqrt(Avg * (1 - Avg) / N)) %>% 
  mutate(U_CI = Avg + 1.96 * sqrt(Avg * (1 - Avg) / N))
SI_avgs
ggplot(SI_avgs, aes(Shift, Avg)) +
  geom_col(fill = "royalblue1") + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = L_CI, ymax = U_CI), width = .25)
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data (not a picture of it), and a clear explanation of what what about this hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `geom_bar` instead of `geom_col` and then use `geom_errorbar`

```
ggplot(data) +
    geom_bar( aes(x=Shift, y=Avg), stat="identity", fill="royalblue1") +
    geom_errorbar( aes(x=Shift, ymin=Avg-sd, ymax=Avg+sd), width=0.25)
```